# Different response for same method of DatabaseMetaData pointing to different databases?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

When I invoke the method [`getIndexInfo( catalog, schema, table, true, false )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)), I receive a ResultSet slightly different from what is described:

1. With MySQL (5.7), I receive a ResultSet containing:

   - one row corresponding to the primary key column description
   - *n* rows corresponding to the unique columns description
2. With SQL Server (14.00), I receive a ResultSet containing:

   - one row corresponding to the tableIndexStatistic of the primary key
   - one row corresponding to the primary key column description
   - *n* rows corresponding to the unique columns description
   - *m* rows corresponding to the index columns description

Due to a project choice all the primary keys are auto-increment, so there aren't case where a primary key column is also a unique column.

I'm searching to write a solution database-independent, since it will be used for both MySQL and SQL Server databases;

MySQL use the MySQL-AB JDBC Driver 5.1.20, SQL Server use the Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4.

Initially I "resolved" this problem retrieving from the session the driver name, in order to apply a specific filter for each database; 
for MySQL i found that the column `INDEX_NAME` for the Primary Key is always `'PRIMARY'`, meanwhile for SQL Server I found that the column `TYPE` is:

- 0 for the tableIndexStatistic
- 1 for our SQL Server Primary Keys (tableIndexClustered )
- 2 (not found in my case yet, but is for tableIndexHashed )
- 3 for the Unique keys ( tableIndexOther )

A difference between MySQL and SQL Server is that the Primary Keys are respectively of `TYPE` **3** and **1**.

Filter example:

```java
String driver = session.getConfiguration().getDatabaseId();
DatabaseMetaData metadata = session.getConnection().getMetaData();

ResultSet result = metadata.getIndexInfo(catalog, schema, table, true, false);

while( result.next() ){
    if( "mysql".equals(driver) ){
        if( !"PRIMARY".equals((String) result.getObject("INDEX_NAME"))){
            ... code to save the result ...
        }
    } else if ( "sqlserver".equals(driver) ){
        if( 3 == (short) result.getObject("TYPE")){
            ... code to save the result ...       
        } 
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

This code worked for a bit, until I discovered on SQL Server a table with an index; in this case, as per documentation linked before, the indexes are part of the tableIndexOther so they have the column `TYPE` with the value **3**.

At this point I've noticed that the column `NON_UNIQUE` is **true** for the Unique columns descriptions and **false** for the Index columns descriptions.

So I was thinking to proceed expanding the SQL Server filter including the `NON_UNIQUE` column but, against as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)), when I retrieve a tableIndexStatistic I'll get `null` instead of `false`.

I'm a bit confused of how I should approach all those inconsistencies with the documentation, since my main goal is to retrieve the same result of unique keys from those two databases.

Comment: The MySQL 5.1.20 JDBC driver is very old, and Microsoft SQL Server 6.4 is not the latest version (unless you really need to use Java 7). I suggest that you first update to more recent versions and recheck. For MySQL Connector/J the latest version is 8.0.16, for Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver the latest version is 7.2.2. The JDBC API documentation is leading, and if there are inconsistencies with the documentation, then you should report a bug with MySQL or Microsoft.

Comment: Unluckily i need Java 7, so for now i think i'll follow your suggestion to report a bug to MySQL, Microsoft and warn Oracle(?) about those inconsistence in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation specifies that is how a driver has to work, so there is no need to 'warn' Oracle. But I strongly suggest that you first check with a more recent MySQL Connector/J driver, as I said, 5.1.20 is pretty old.